# Battery Life in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, battery

Today i had fresh installation of ubuntu 14.04
previously i had ubuntu 12.04 and had 5 to 6 hours of battery backup even at constant work, but in 14.04 getting 3 hrs only, tried with tlp but no use.

`lspci`:

```
0:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: What graphics are you using, with what driver (use `lspci -v`)? Also, you can use [`indicator-cpufreq`](http://askubuntu.com/a/37997/178596) to save a bit of battery.

Answer (score 1):

First remove `sudo apt-get remove tlp`

install cpu-freq:-

```
cd && wget -O .laptop-mode.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/improve-battery/laptop-mode



chmod +x .laptop-mode.sh && ./.laptop-mode.sh
```

[image]

If You running GPU Nvidia/AMD change setting to Intel Mode.
[image: As show in picture]